# Objective C methods naming conventions

Tags: objective-c, naming-conventions

What name is better for the "delete" method that deletes document in database with given documentID?

1) 
    `-(void) deleteDocumentWithID:(NSString *) documentID error:(NSError **)error;`

or

2) 
    `-(void) deleteDocumentByID:(NSString *) documentID error:(NSError **)error;`

Comment: By or With ID is up to you (I'd prefer withID). But the parameters should be of type `NSString*` and `NSError**`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Programming with Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Conventions/Conventions.html)

- Method names do not have a prefix
- Method should start with a lowercase letter
- [camel case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) is used for multiple words
- If a method takes one or more arguments, the name of the method
  should indicate each parameter
- Error should be the last parameter to the method

[image]

By and with depends on you

```
 -(void) deleteDocumentWithID:(NSString *) documentID error:(NSError **)error;

 -(void) deleteDocumentByID:(NSString *) documentID error:(NSError **)error;
```

Comment: And from the point of English grammar, what is better in this case "By " or "With" ?

Answer (score 2):

Your naming conventions are completely up to you, as mentioned in the apple doc try and be as descriptive as possible with your method names so any third party looking at your code (header file) will be able to get an idea quickly on what the method does. From the code you posted you are on the right track.

Have a look at this document.

[Apple Conventions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Conventions/Conventions.html)